# Problems installing BasicTex on Mac OS

Tags: installing, texlive, mactex

I was following [this tutorial](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/BasicTeX.pdf) to install BasicTex. Running `latex` command immediately returns without any warning or error. My environment variables are:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/bin/universal-darwin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
$ which latex
/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/bin/universal-darwin/latex
```

How should I troubleshoot it further?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @PeterJansson, thanks. Are you implying that this question is off topic or incomplete?

Comment: Not at all. All new user first posts are reviewed (mandated by the system) and users welcomed to the site. This review also allows us to provide pointers to new users if necessary.

Comment: @Kimi Peter's was just a welcome. I never recommend installing BasicTeX, which lacks too many useful packages. What's the output of `latex -version`?

Comment: @egreg, no output at all, command returns immediately. I thought, that you can install missing packages later?

Comment: @Kimi Hunting through the list of packages is usually painful. Install the complete MacTeX and live happy. ;-)

Comment: @egreg, would you recommend to uninstall BasicTex before installing MacTeX? If yes, any recommendations how?

Comment: @Kimi `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2012basic`

Comment: @egreg, thanks, after installing MacTeX it works :)